# How to see the c# code detail in visual studio using F12?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm the new of `c#` and visual studio. when I use the <kbd>F12</kbd> to go to definition, but sometime it didn't work. it just showed me the a code without the body/logic of the methods.

Someone told me because of `dll`, but I really don't know how to do can see the detailed code in this case.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others said, it's because all VS has to go on is the DLL, which doesn't contain the source, only method signatures.

But what can you do about it?

A few things.

1. Try ReSharper, which has a built-in decompiler and can show you some code (note that it won't be formatted and with variable names of the original, but it's usually better than nothing).
2. If you don't have ReSharper, you can use the free JetBrains dotPeek product, although that's not integrated into Visual Studio.
3. If you reference from Nuget.org, then you should be able to turn on an option in VS that will download sources (if provided by the package author) in the form of pdb files. This is the best experience.
4. If possible, get your hands on some matching pdb files. Either get them direct, build from source etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you didn't add reference as a project but you are pointing to a `dll` or `exe` using Browse tab in Add Reference dialog. If you add reference using Projects tab you should go directly to the source code when you select Go To Definition.

> **Note:** If you do not have project for the `dll` then you will get `metadata` only from `dll`

Comment: Yeah, I open the code shown "from metadata". So,do  I have no way to see the source code?

Comment: Do you have project for referenced `dll`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have known it.

Answer (score 1):

If your definition you are going to find using <kbd>F12</kbd> is in the same project, then it will show total definition of method/variable/class.

If your definition is outside the project i,e you are referencing different project, then it will show only declaration.

Comment: Can I see the detail in outside project?

Comment: if have that referenced project code, open the project and check for method your are searching

Comment: if you have only dll, try to download a tool called relector exe, and open the dll using this tool, you can see the code of the dll there.

Comment: where can I find the dll file ? Thanks for your answer, I have clicked the Up.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to view the source code of a method you're referencing from a compiled DLL, you can't, because it's compiled code, and therefore it isn't source code.

Comment: Does it have something like xx.source.jar in c# to see the source code?

Comment: Not as part of the DLL, no. The source code would be distributed separately (assuming that the component is open-source. If it's a proprietary component you almost certainly won't be given the source, obviously).