# Issue replicating C# enumerator interfaces

Tags: c#

For my project I need to replicate C# enumerator interface hierarchy. I proceeded by simply copy&paste&rename from VS F12:

```
  public interface IMyEnumerator {
    object Current { get; }
    bool MoveNext();
    void Reset();
  }

  public interface IMyEnumerator<out T> : IMyEnumerator, IDisposable {
    T Current { get; }
  }

  public interface IMyEnumerable {
    IMyEnumerator GetEnumerator();
  }

  public interface IMyEnumerable<out T> : IMyEnumerable {
    IMyEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator();
  }

  public class MyContainer : IMyEnumerable<T>, IMyEnumerable {
    ...
  }
}
```

I get warnings about `IMyEnumerator<out T>.Current` hiding `IMyEnumerator.Current` and `IMyEnumerable<out T>.GetEnumerator` hiding `IMyEnumerable.GetEnumerator` with a recommndation to add the `new` keyword.

Should I be adding the `new` keyword in this case ? I am a bit unsure about the implications as the matching sources for IEnumerator and IEnumerable (at least as seen from VS F12) do not have the new keyword, see:

```
namespace System.Collections {
  //
  // Summary:
  //     Supports a simple iteration over a non-generic collection.
  public interface IEnumerator {
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets the element in the collection at the current position of the enumerator.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     The element in the collection at the current position of the enumerator.
    object Current { get; }

    //
    // Summary:
    //     Advances the enumerator to the next element of the collection.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     true if the enumerator was successfully advanced to the next element; false if
    //     the enumerator has passed the end of the collection.
    //
    // Exceptions:
    //   T:System.InvalidOperationException:
    //     The collection was modified after the enumerator was created.
    bool MoveNext();
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Sets the enumerator to its initial position, which is before the first element
    //     in the collection.
    //
    // Exceptions:
    //   T:System.InvalidOperationException:
    //     The collection was modified after the enumerator was created.
    void Reset();
  }
  //
  // Summary:
  //     Exposes an enumerator, which supports a simple iteration over a non-generic collection.
  public interface IEnumerable {
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Returns an enumerator that iterates through a collection.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     An System.Collections.IEnumerator object that can be used to iterate through
    //     the collection.
    IEnumerator GetEnumerator();
  }
}

namespace System.Collections.Generic {
  //
  // Summary:
  //     Supports a simple iteration over a generic collection.
  //
  // Type parameters:
  //   T:
  //     The type of objects to enumerate.
  public interface IEnumerator<out T> : IEnumerator, IDisposable {
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets the element in the collection at the current position of the enumerator.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     The element in the collection at the current position of the enumerator.
    T Current { get; }
  }

  //
  // Summary:
  //     Exposes the enumerator, which supports a simple iteration over a collection of
  //     a specified type.
  //
  // Type parameters:
  //   T:
  //     The type of objects to enumerate.
  public interface IEnumerable<out T> : IEnumerable {
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Returns an enumerator that iterates through the collection.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     An enumerator that can be used to iterate through the collection.
    IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator();
  }
}
```

Comment: What makes you unsure?

Comment: @gunr2171 what makes me unsure is the fact that the matching sources for `IEnumerator<out T>` and `IEnumerable<out T>` (at least as seen from VS F12) do not have the `new` keyword

Comment: You should almost always avoid `new` to shadow methods. Death and carnage comes to all who shadow.

Comment: @kofifus - Can you please provide verbatim the source you copied?

Comment: [.NET Framework `IEnumerator<T>` source](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/ienumerator.cs#L32) and [.NET Core `IEnumerator<T>` source](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Generic/IEnumerator.cs#L15)

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar oh that explains it .. F12 crap .. if you post a quick answer I'll mark it thanks!

Comment: I don't think the `new` keyword has any impact on the IL output by the C# compiler. The only purpose of the keyword is to squash this warning. https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQMwAJboMLoN7LpGYYBGA9uQDboBC+A5gKYAuA3AL7JcoZYAiIXASTES6CtTqNWnbkA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you refer to the source code, you'll see that `IEnumerator<T>` does actually use the `new` keyword:

```
public interface IEnumerator<out T> : IDisposable, IEnumerator
{
    // Returns the current element of the enumeration. The returned value is
    // undefined before the first call to MoveNext and following a
    // call to MoveNext that returned false. Multiple calls to
    // GetCurrent with no intervening calls to MoveNext
    // will return the same object.
    new T Current
    {
        get;
    }
}
```

Sources:

- [.NET Framework `IEnumerator<T>`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/ienumerator.cs#L32)
- [.NET Framework `IEnumerator`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/collections/ienumerator.cs#L42)
- [.NET Core `IEnumerator<T>`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Generic/IEnumerator.cs#L15)
- [.NET Core `IEnumerator`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/IEnumerator.cs#L26)

Answer (score 3):

The reference source on https://referencesource.microsoft.com shows that both [`IEnumerator<T>.Current`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/ienumerator.cs,893e8cdebffde2da) and [`IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/ienumerable.cs,3acf01620172c7f0) have the `new` modifier.

Visual Studio doesn't show it possibly because you are viewing the dll metadata, which only has the method signatures, and that doesn't include the `new` modifier. You'd need to see the decompiled code to see the `new` modifier. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38369759/how-to-see-the-c-sharp-code-detail-in-visual-studio-using-f12) for a similar question about Visual Studio not showing everything.

There is really not much of a deep implication here. It is just warning you that `IEnumerator<T>.Current` and `IEnumerable.Current` are two different properties, rather than the former *overriding* the latter. If you are aware of that (which I think you are already), add a `new` to show that you are aware.

Just in case you don't understand what I mean by "`IEnumerator<T>.Current` and `IEnumerable.Current` are two different properties", think about how you would implement your interfaces. Here is a very minimal implementation:

```
public class MyContainer<T> : IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerator<T> {
    private T t;
    
    public MyContainer(T t) { this.t = t; }
      
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() => this; // 1
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => this.GetEnumerator(); // 2
    
    public T Current => this.Current; // 1
    object IEnumerator.Current => t; // 2
      
    public bool MoveNext() => true;
    public void Reset() {}
    public void Dispose() {}
}
```

Notice that I implemented `Current` and `GetEnumerator` twice each. I could have made them do different things, but I didn't here. I just made the ones marked "2" delegate to the ones marked "1".

If I call `GetEnumerator` through a variable of type `IEnumerable`, I would call the implementation marked "2", otherwise I would have called the implementation marked "1",

```
void Foo(IEnumerable x, IEnumerable<int> y) {
    x.GetEnumerator(); // Implementation "2"
    y.GetEnumerator(); // Implementation "1"
}
```

and this is what it meant by "hiding",